# Triangle not showing

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am trying to display a triangle in an image. Unfortunately, is doesn't display the triangle and I can't find the reason for that. Where did I mess up?
Here is the code:

```
    double hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((width_index-standard),2)+Math.pow((high_index-base_index),2));
    angle *= Math.asin(((width_index-standard)/hypotenuse));
    angle = angle*(180/Math.PI);
    angle = Math.round(angle);
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_angle);
    t.setText(String.valueOf(angle));

    // return_b is the bitmap to be displayed
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(return_b);
    Path p = new Path();
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    p.moveTo(standard, (base_index+(float)hypotenuse));
    p.lineTo(standard, height-1);
    p.moveTo(standard, height-1);
    p.lineTo(width_index, high_index);
    p.moveTo(width_index, high_index);
    //p.addArc(standard, (base_index+(float)hypotenuse), width_index, high_index, 0, (float)((-1)*angle));
    p.lineTo(standard, (base_index+(float)hypotenuse));
    p.close();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
```

Thanks.

Comment: @azurefrog I think "doesn't display the triangle" is a clear enough description of what goes wrong, in a program that is clearly supposed to display a triangle.

Comment: I see you're trying to render stuff on a new canvas but I there's no evidence the canvas would be associated with anything in the view hierarchy.

Comment: @laalto `return_b` is the bitmap to be displayed. It is associated with the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the `moveTo`s. When I removed them the triangle showed up.